# Remember password popup on Android webview problem

Tags: android, passwords, popup, webview, passwordbox

this is is a pretty straight forward question, I need to detect when the default Remember password popup opens on the Android Webview (So I can make sure I am not covering it with any other component, or at least bring it to the front)

Thanks a lot, this community has been very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear remembered password first with this code:

```
WebViewDatabase.getInstance(this).clearUsernamePassword();
```

After that remember password popup will displayed.